# Couldn't create mapping policy - iOS Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've been trying to use a custom migration policy in an application I'm putting together. So far migrations have worked from v1 -> v2 when using a mapping model. However, whenever I add a custom policy to an entity mapping, the migration refuses to work for v2 -> v3.

Custom Migration Policy:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class ObjectCustomV2V3Migration: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {

override func createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance(sInstance: NSManagedObject, entityMapping mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {

    var newObject:NSManagedObject? = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(mapping.destinationEntityName!, inManagedObjectContext: manager.destinationContext) as? NSManagedObject

    // Sets attr31 - string attribute
    var str:String = sInstance.valueForKey("attr21") as String
    if str == "" {
        str = "BlanketyBlank"
    }
    newObject?.setValue(str, forKey: "attr31")

    // Sets attr32 (int16 attribute) as double of value in previous version
    // ignore the dodgy type casting.
    var num:Int = sInstance.valueForKey("attr22") as Int
    num *= 2
    var num16 = NSNumber(integer: num)

    newObject?.setValue(num16, forKey: "attr32")



    if newObject != nil {
        manager.associateSourceInstance(sInstance, withDestinationInstance: newObject!, forEntityMapping: mapping)
        return true
    }


    return false


   }
}
```

and when I run the app, the following error is returned:

```
2015-07-10 14:32:42.952 SingleDBMigration[2153:739674] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6C142EC2-02DB-4BD6-8428-5739C57C7795/Documents/SingleDBMigration.sqlite options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 0;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)" UserInfo=0x17ecad70 {NSUnderlyingException=Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (ObjectCustomV2V3Migration)} with userInfo dictionary {
    NSUnderlyingException = "Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (ObjectCustomV2V3Migration)";
}
2015-07-10 14:32:42.965 SingleDBMigration[2153:739674] Unresolved error Optional(Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo=0x17eaf880 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x17ecad90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.}), Optional([NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134110.)" UserInfo=0x17ecad70 {NSUnderlyingException=Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (ObjectCustomV2V3Migration)}, NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.])
```

with the important part being:

```
NSUnderlyingException=Couldn't create mapping policy for class named (ObjectCustomV2V3Migration)
```

I've tried the few questions I have found on this problem, and none of them have provided any satisfactory solutions. I'd be very thankful if anybody could shed any light on the issue I'm facing!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My issue was that my project name had spaces in it, so in the mapping model editor the custom policy should be specified using underscores instead of spaces when specifying the Swift module name.

For example, to specify the `MyCustomMigrationPolicy` class in the project named **My App Name**, I used the following custom policy in the editor:

`My_App_Name.MyCustomMigrationPolicy`

Comment: If your project name has "-" then they should also be converted "_"

Comment: My project name has "." inside it, and I also need to replace "." with "_"

Answer (score 44):

I eventually solved this, after understanding an answer to a similar question. I had forgotten to add the project namespace, so rather than setting the custom policy name as `ObjectCustomV2V3Migration` in the Mapping Model, I should have used `ProjectModuleName.ObjectCustomV2V3Migration`.

Comment: I also solved, but I changed my implementation. In my case I could use the `Filter predicate` option instead of an custom policy. Up for decipher the error you were getting

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :) I wish XCode had more helpful error messages, or at least more detailed explanations!

Comment: Thank you so much :) Was struggling from 4-5 hours.

Comment: Seems the model editor team is more on point than the mapping editor team ;)

Comment: Worth linking to the project name -> Swift module name mapping https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID138

Comment: How would you scale this with multiple targets? I tried using `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)` without any luck so far...

Comment: @adauguet for multiple targets I ended up creating multiple mapping models, each for a target. It is a pain :(

Comment: Do NOT preface it with the PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME if the Policy is written in Objective C and NOT Swift.

Comment: @adauguet for multiple targets you can check my answer. I used `@objc(name)` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the module name as a prefix in the mapping model is one way to solve this issue, but on multi-target projects you have to create one mapping model per target.

On the other hand, you can mark the custom policy class with `@objc(name)` attribute and expose the name of your class to Objective-C runtime without module name in front, like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(ObjectCustomV2V3Migration)
class ObjectCustomV2V3Migration: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {
    ...
}
```

That way, you don't need to prefix your class name with the module name in the mapping model:

[image]